# Get key from xml attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got this SimpleXmlElement:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#625
  +"productCategoryAttribute": array:4 [
    0 => "Yes"
    1 => "No"
    2 => "Maybe"
    3 => "Yes"
  ]
}
```

I get it like:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(Storage::get($path));
```

This is the original xml:

```
<productCategoryAttributes>
    <productCategoryAttribute key="long">Yes</productCategoryAttribute>
    <productCategoryAttribute key="short">No</productCategoryAttribute>
    <productCategoryAttribute key="long">Maybe</productCategoryAttribute>
    <productCategoryAttribute key="short">Yes</productCategoryAttribute>
</productCategoryAttributes>
```

My question is how do I get the keys as wel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to access a specific attribute is just by using an array index - `['key']` in this case:

```
foreach ($xml->productCategoryAttribute as $attribute) {
  echo (string) $attribute['key'], ' = ', (string) $attribute, PHP_EOL;
}
```

> long = Yes
>
> short = No
>
> long = Maybe
>
> short = Yes

See https://eval.in/936504

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the attributes of the element using `SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`:

```
foreach($productCategoryAttributes as $element) {
    $attrs = $element->attributes();
    echo 'key = ' . $attrs['key'];
    echo 'value = ' . $element;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't. `$attrs = $element->attributes(); $key = $attrs['key'];` is exactly the same as `$key = $element['key'];` unless there are multiple namespaces involved.